# Probability in a box with $21$ cards with coloured sides

Tags: probability, solution-verification

A box contains 21 cards, 9 of them are red on both sides, 7 of them are black on both sides and the remaining 5 cards are red on one side and black on the other side.

(a) Calculate the probability that placing all 21 cards on the table randomly, the black sides are more than the red sides.

Now I take randomly only one card from the 21 and I put it down on the table. If both sides are red, I win 1 euro, if both sides are black, I win 2 euros and if the sides are different, I lose 1 euro.

(b) What is my average earnings?

(c) If I have a positive earnings, what is the probability that the card has both black sides?

(d) If the side that I see is red, what is the probability that the hidden side is black?

My answers:

(a) In every case, I always have 9 red sides and 7 black side and only 5 sides are variable. The only situations in which the number of the black sides is greater than the number of the red ones are the cases where all of the 5 variable cards are on the black side or 4 out of 5 of them are on the black side.

If I define $X_i$ as a Bernoulli random variable that is equal to $1$ if the side of the card is black and is equal to $0$ if the side of the card is red, both cases with probability $p=1/2$, I have to calculate $\mathbb{P}(S_5> 3)$ where $S_5=X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4+X_5$ is a binomial random variable (I can suppose that every card is independent from the others). So, I have that

$$\mathbb{P}(S_5>3)=\sum_{k=4}^5 {{5}\choose{k}} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^5={{5}\choose{4}}\cdot \frac{1}{32}+{{5}\choose{5}}\cdot \frac{1}{32}=\frac{3}{16}$$

(b) Let $V$ the random variable corresponding to the total earning an let $S_2$ the binomial corresponding to the both sides of the taken card where the success is when the side is red and the insuccess is when the side is black.

1. If $S_2=X_1+X_2=0$, then both sides are black (I earn 2 euros)
2. If $S_2=X_1+X_2=1$, then the sides are different (I lose 1 euro)
3. If $S_2=X_1+X_2=2$, then both sides are red (I earn 1 euro)

So, the image of $V$ is $\{-1,1,2\}$ and I have that

$$\mathbb{E}(V)=-1\cdot \mathbb{P}(S_2=1)+1\cdot \mathbb{P}(S_2=2)+2\cdot \mathbb{P}(S_2=0)=$$

$$=-1\cdot {{2}\choose{1}} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+1\cdot {{2}\choose{2}} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+2\cdot {{2}\choose{0}} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=$$

$$=\frac{1}{4}=0.25\quad € $$

(c) I use the Bayes's formula:

$$ \mathbb{P}(S_2=0|V>0)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(V>0|S_2=0)\mathbb{P}(S_2=0)}{\mathbb{P}(V>0)}=\frac{1\cdot \frac{1}{4}}{\frac{2}{3}}=\frac{3}{8}$$

(d) I have to calculate $\mathbb{P}(X_2=0|X_1=1)$.

$$\mathbb{P}(X_2=0|X_1=1)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X_2=0,X_1=1)}{\mathbb{P}(X_1=1)}=\frac{\frac{5}{12}}{\frac{14}{21}}=\frac{5}{8}$$

Is it correct? Any suggestions, in particular in (c), (d)?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is that if I draw a card, it's a binomial that counts the number of sides. If $S_1 = 1$, then there should be two different ways for this to happen, since red-black and black-red count, but these aren't two events its just $1$ event. Also you have a $50$% chance that a side is red, which isn't true. Finally, these are not independent trials, my first side being red affects the probability of my next side being red. That's why all parts b,c, and d are incorrect.

Retry this problem by taking a simpler approach where you don't use a binomial at all, and instead look at it combinatorically. You can define $V$ by:

$$V = \begin{cases}1 & \text{if card drawn is red-red} \\ 2 & \text{if card drawn is black-black} \\ -1 & \text{if card drawn is red-black}\end{cases}$$

and then find the probbaility of each event.

For reference the answers should be (do your own work first and use these to check):

> $\frac{6}{7}, \frac{7}{16}, \frac{5}{14}$.